# How to write scraped data into a csv file via python?

Tags: python-3.x, url, python-requests, data-analysis, stock

I downloaded historical stock data via the following code.

```
url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/RELIANCE.BO?period1=1577110559&period2=1608732959&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
r = requests.get(url)
```

Then I tried to write it in a `csv` file via this code.

```
open('ril.csv').write(r.content)
```

But it gave an error prompt as

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified code:

```
url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/RELIANCE.BO?period1=1577110559&period2=1608732959&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
r = requests.get(url)
open('ril.csv','wb').write(r.content)
```

data was downloaded in binary form, so we need to read and write it in binary form too.